# Error when using Nokogiri within model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm trying to develop a model method that will scrape a url that comes in from a post request to the controller. While I'm able to successfully use Nokogiri from the controller, when I try to move the logic into the model I'm always getting the error:

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - "www.url.com"

Why won't Rails allow me to implement Nokogiri in a model?

```
The model method I have setup as:

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class UrlContent < ApplicationRecord
    validates :content, presence: true

    def self.parser(url)
        binding.pry
        html = open(url)
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
        content = doc.css('h1, h2, h3, a').map(&:text).join(" ")
        content
    end 

end
```

And my controller looks like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class UrlContentsController < ApplicationController

skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token  


    def create
        content = UrlContent.parser(params[:content])
        binding.pry
        render layout: false
    end 

    def index
        @url_contents = UrlContent.all
        render json: @url_contents, status: 200, layout: false
    end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're calling `open` with something that you think is a URL but really isn't. You say this:

```
html = open(url)
```

and you're getting a complaint about `open` not being able to find a *file* named `'www.url.com'` so you're actually saying:

```
html = open('www.url.com')
```

when you mean something more like:

```
html = open('http://www.url.com')
```

You should be checking your URLs and adding schemes if they don't have them already. I usually use Addressable for this sort of thing, something like this:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
url = "http://#{url}" if(!uri.scheme)
```

Comment: thank you! how do you include Addressable in the model after installing the gem? i tried require "addressable/uri" and it gives me an error

Comment: Just `gem 'addressable'` in your `Gemfile` should be enough. Did you `bundle install` after updating your `Gemfile`?

Comment: You can also use [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) from the standard Ruby library but Addressable generally behaves better.